# Scheduled task to assign SQL permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a scheduled task which assigns permissions to new SQL Server 2008 databases. At least once a week we spin up a new web application where some AD security groups need to be added manually as db_owners. I would ideally like a script that runs daily which assigns the permissions to new or any existing databases.

The database named are always prefixed with 'CRM_'. I cannot find any examples on the web which match my requirements and was wondering if anyone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: just use the gui to do it once and instead of "save/ok" click the script button in the upper left corner.

Comment: The database name is going to be different so how would I set it to assign permissions to any database with the name like "crm%' ?

Comment: You can either add the script with the database as a variable to the create script for the database, like make a big script with all your "getting started" code or you can make some dynamic sql with a cursor but that is a last resort. If you post some sample code of what you actually want to do and some more context I can give you some more pointers.